# Vibrate android phone from non-activity class

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make my android phone vibrate after the ball hits the target in the game, so I created inner class `Vibrate` which extend Activity as my outer class is non-activity

```
public class TheGame extends GameThread {
  public class Vibrate extends Activity {
    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
  }
//some methods 

  protected void updateGame(float secondsElapsed){
    //updating coordinates and if ball hits the target >> vibrate 
    TheGame.Vibrate vib = new TheGame.Vibrate();
    vib.v.vibrate(500);

  }
 }
```

How can I call a vibration (`Vibration v` -inner class) from an outer class?? At this moment program stops at shows "unfortunately, app has stopped" and "too much output to process android" in Logcat
//////////

Finally worked by the help of dhke. I just needed to access getSystemService(...) from Context which I Extended in outer class.

Comment: Why doesn't the `GameThread` have access to a `Context` object somewhere? Or more precisely: Who creates the `GameThread` object?

Comment: I don't know who creates the object but do we need GameThread object??

Comment: You will need access to a `Context` object that has to be given to you by the framework. Your program crashing should really tell you that you *cannot* create activities using `new`, they are intended to be created by the framework and have quite a complex lifecycle. But you don't need an activity to access the vibrator, you need a `Context`.  So again: Who creates the `GameThread` and can the creator supply a `Context` object (or an already obtained vibrator) to the thread?

Comment: It hard for me to give an answer but GameThread is one more class in framework and in it we have `private Context mContext;` -- so, i guess that it provides context object

Comment: Yep, so you should be easily able to use `mContext.getSystemService(...)` without having to use the activity at to obtain the vibrator.

Comment: Ok, but Context has a private access so do I need to change it to public??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82833/discussion-between-user3791431-and-dhke).

Answer (score 1):

Call static method in **Non Activity** class:

```
public class MyNonActivity{
    public static void vibrateDevice(Context mContext){
       Vibrator v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
       // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
       v.vibrate(500);
    }
}
```

Add permission in **Manifest** file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

How to **call** from **Activity**:

```
MyNonActivity.vibrateDevice(getApplicationContext());
```

**Done**